# Write a snippet of C/C++ code that creates this list of base-12 numbers that count from 0000 to BBBB

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, printing

Im not sure what to do i want it to print 0000 to ending in BBBB i was trying to use the printf statement anyways, if anyone can help me figure this out that would be great.  Thanks

```
            #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
    char digits[] = "0123456789AB";
    for (int column1=0; column1<=12; column1++)  {  
    for (int column2=0; column2<=12; column2++) {   
    for (int column3=0; column3<=12; column3++) {
    for (int column4=0; column4<=12; column4++) {

    std::cout<< digits[column2]<<endl; 
        }

        }}}




    return(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4 for loops are not the prettiest thing ever, but they should work and I'm not sure it's worth the complications to do it differently. So keep what you have, just print all digits:

```
std::cout<< digits[column1]<< digits[column2] << digits[column3] << digits[column4]<<endl;
```

Comment: Thanks both methods work but this was easier for me to understand.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's better to parametrize the base and the column count to avoid many nested `for`'s.

```
#include <iostream>

const int columnCount = 4, base = 12;

char digitToChar(int digit) {
    if(digit >= 0 && digit <= 9) {
        return '0' + digit;
    } else {
        return 'A' + digit - 10;
    }
}

bool increment(int* number) {
    int currentColumn = columnCount - 1;
    ++number[currentColumn];
    while(number[currentColumn] == base) {
        number[currentColumn] = 0;
        --currentColumn;
        if(currentColumn < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        ++number[currentColumn];
    }
    return true;
}

void outputNumber(int* number) {
    for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
        std::cout << digitToChar(number[i]);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int number[columnCount] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    bool overflow = false;
    do {
        outputNumber(number);
        overflow = !increment(number);
    } while(!overflow);
    return 0;
}
```